# Windows Server 2003 - Install with an OEM key without OEM media

Tags: windows-server-2003, licensing, oem

Is there any way to use an OEM key to install windows 2003 when OEM media is not available?  I have an OEM key from the hardware supplier, but we do not yet have the media for this and the server is currently installed (but not activated) using a MAPS copy of windows 2003 (the license for this won't cover production use, hence the additional key purchase)

I'd prefer not to wait and reinstall once we have OEM media, so I'm after either a way to get an OEM disk image or a way to use an OEM key in a non-OEM install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an OEM media, that's actually a different media from retail and VLK, so you can't use OEM keys on those other ones.

You can try "looking around" for it, IYKWIM; as long as you have a proper license key, it doesn't actually matter *where* did you get the media.

Comment: Oh man, another acronym I needed to google for

Comment: Many vendors have OEM media, find a mid sized shop that builds their own systems, they might be able to sell, burn a copy or worst case do the install for you, for a $$ I'm sure.